# Trying to add if statement to a script

Tags: bash

So the following command displays the domain name: `dsconfigad -show | grep "y Domain" | awk '{print $5}'`

I'm trying to write an if statement where if the result of the above command is lets say "test.us" then stop the script and if it doesn't, continue the script.

Here is what I have so far:

```
DOMAINNAME="test.us"

dsconfigad -show | grep "y Domain" | awk '{print $5}'
if [ "$DOMAINNAME" = "test.us" ]
then
    echo "Domain name is correct. Exiting script."
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DOMAINNAME=$(dsconfigad -show | grep "y Domain" | awk '{print $5}')
if [ "$DOMAINNAME" = "test.us" ]
then
    echo "Domain name is correct. Exiting script."
    exit 1
fi
```

The $() will execute the command within and the output will be stored in the DOMAINNAME variable.

Comment: You are a legend. Thank you for taking the time to look at that.